# Compartir contenido de dos tablas relacionadas MySql

Tags: mysql, ionic, angular4

**MYSQL**

Tengo dos tablas en mysql, a continuacion evidencio el modelo:
[image: Equipos y Jugadores]
En las cuales necesito recuperar todos los jugadores a los cuales pertenecen a un club en especifico. por ejemplo: Real Madrid y toda su plantilla.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  
eqpo.nombre_equipo,
jdrs.nombre_jugador
FROM equipos eqpo
INNER JOIN ciudad cdad
ON cdad.id_ciudad = eqpo.id_ciudad_equipo
INNER JOIN jugadores jdrs
ON jdrs.id_equipo_jugador = eqpo.id_equipos

WHERE eqpo.id_equipos = '3'
```

**REQUERIMIENTOS**

1. Requiero mostrar en una primer tabla HTML el listado de los equipos de futbol de la liga española.
2. Al darle clic en detalles se evidencie el listado de la plantilla del equipo seleccionado.

**EJEMPLO 1**

[image: Requerimiento 1]

**EJEMPLO 2**

[image: Requerimiento 2]

**PROBLEMA**

pero con la consulta obtengo todos los nombres y en los cuales se repite el club al cual pertenece, por lo que al mostrarlo en la tabla se va a repetir 20 o 25 veces el nombre del equipo del Real Madrid, del Barcelona, del Villarreal, etc.

[image: Listado Query]

Comment: Hola @jecorrales, si quitas del SELECT la columna eqpo.nombre_equipo?

Comment: @Nicola seria una opcion, pero para generar los detalles del equipo tengo que tenerlo cargado previamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es agrupar tus consultas de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    eqpo.nombre_equipo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(jdrs.nombre_jugador) AS jugadores
    FROM equipos eqpo
    INNER JOIN ciudad cdad
    ON cdad.id_ciudad = eqpo.id_ciudad_equipo
    INNER JOIN jugadores jdrs
    ON jdrs.id_equipo_jugador = eqpo.id_equipos
    WHERE eqpo.id_equipos = '3'
    GROUP BY eqpo.nombre_equipo
```

Con esto lo que estás haciendo es pedir que los resultados se agrupen por el nombre del equipo y que los nombres de los jugadores se agrupen en una sola columna para lo que se separan por comas, un ejemplo del resultado sería:

| eqpo.nombre_equipo | jugadores |
| | |
| 'equipo1' | 'Pedro, Juan, Mario, Jose, Rafael' |
| 'equipo2' | 'Raul, Abraham, Javier, Hector, Hugo' |

Es lo que se me ocurre, aunque para mi sería mucho más óptimo primero solicitar todos los equipos disponibles para una ciudad y luego, dependiendo de en que equipo haga click el usuario hacer una segunda consulta para obtener los jugadores pues de lo contrario estás solicitando todos los jugadores para todos los equipos disponibles para una ciudad, lo cual se traduce en muchos posibles datos que el usuario realmente no necesitará, pero ese es solo un comentario a lo que buscas hacer...

Comment: Es lo que habia pensado, pero aun estoy aprendiendo Typescript y Angular.